# How I can add values to WCF session and use it in Client(WinForm) and in WCF context?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, session

I have an application with WinForm client connected to WCF.
I use the session, I start the session at login and I terminate the session at logout.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IOperazioniUtente
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsOneWay = false)]        
    Utente login(Utente utenteInConnessione);

    ...........
    ...........

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true, IsOneWay = true)]    
    void logout(Utente ute);


}
```

I want to add value to session as  on ASP.NET, it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is a PerSession instance, there is one server instance per client proxy.

So to add an object to the session, just add an object to the server instance, in a collection or any kind of field or property that best fits your management.

For instance :

**1. Service interface**

Quite the same as in the question

```cs
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMessageService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void AddMessageToSession(String msg);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> ListSessionMessages();

}
```

**2. Service implementation**

```cs
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    private List<String> messages = new List<String> ();

    public void AddMessageToSession(string msg)
    {
        messages.Add(msg);
    }
    public List<string> ListSessionMessages()
    {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

**3. Client calls**

One session per client == 1 service instance per caller

```
MessageServiceClient client1 = new MessageServiceClient();
MessageServiceClient client2 = new MessageServiceClient();
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    client1.AddMessageToSession("msg" + i);
client2.AddMessageToSession("msg" );
int nbMessages1 = client1.ListSessionMessages().Count();
int nbMessages2 = client2.ListSessionMessages().Count();
// outputs 5 :
Console.WriteLine("Number of messages in Session 1 : " + nbMessages1);
// outputs 1 :
Console.WriteLine("Number of messages in Session 2 : " + nbMessages2);
```

Regards

Comment: Prego. Just take care of scaling problems. Keeping in memory a  server instance per client can be expensive

Comment: Yes, I know. Sessions is very expensive.
But if I don't use session, is the  proxy  Loaded and Unloaded for every call ?

Comment: I just say take care, the server load depends of the number of clients. On the server side there is a new service per call, if you don't set a session. If you may have a large number of clients at the same time, you may remove the session in the contract, and pass a client ID in every method to retrive some "session" information stored in database. This is more boring, slower, but handles large numbers of clients better.